# Using AspectJ to extend an Entity

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

How can I use AspectJ to extend an Entity. For example say I have one entity Product with attributes like mfgDate,prodIdentifier. For some cases I would like to extend this entity to add new attributes like year,warranty.

Can I do this using AspectJ? The reason I want to do this is so that I can deliver the generic Product and then ask the other team to extend the generic product using Aspect.

Thanks

Comment: why can't the team extend the generic product the old fashion way?

Comment: we cannot use the traditional way because we cannot extend entities having annotations like @Embeddeble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about [Inter-type Declarations](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-interType.html).

Comment: thanks; Thats what I was looking for. Just one question; can we do this for Entities (JPA) also?

Comment: Sure. Final classes behaves like if you created them good old OOP way :)